# Loop through files in a subdirectory, append filenames as dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a directory of text files in a subdirectory, `/directory_name/`. I would like to loop through all files within this subdirectory, and append the filename as a string as the dictionary key. Then I would like to take the first word in each text file, and use this as the value for each key. I'm a bit stuck on this part:

```
import os

os.path.expanduser(~/directory_name/)   # go to subdirectory

file_dict = {}  # create dictionary

for i in file_directory:
    file_dict[str(filename)] = {}  # creates keys based on each filename
    # do something here to get the dictionary values
```

Is it possible to do this in two separate steps? That is, create dictionary keys first, then do an operation on all text files to extract the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change directories, use `os.chdir()`. Assuming the first word in each file is followed by a space,

```
import os


file_dict = {}  # create a dictionary
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), directory_name))
for key in [file for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if os.path.isfile(file)]:
    value = open(key).readlines()[0].split()[0]
    file_dict[key] = value
```

works for me. And if you really want to do it in two steps,

```
import os


os.chdir(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), directory_name))
keys = [file for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if os.path.isfile(file)]  # step 1

# Do something else in here...

values = [open(key).readlines()[0].split()[0] for key in keys]  # step 2

file_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))  # Map values onto keys to create the dictionary
```

gives the same output.

Comment: Just to be clear: you have used the above to define dictionary keys?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang That's right; the file names are stored as the keys. So if your files are `'file_one'`, `'file_two'`, and `'file_three'`, and the first words in each are `'foo'`, `'bar'`, and `'lorem'`, the dictionary will be `{'file_one': 'foo', 'file_two': 'bar', 'file_three': 'lorem'}`

Comment: Does this have to be done simultaneously? Will the "correct" value be paired with the corresponding key if done separately?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to do it separately. I'm not sure what advantage there is to doing it separately, but what I wrote will do what I think you're describing.

Comment: Thanks. My previously confusion has been cleared up.